# migration from Spek 1.x to Spek 2.x error

Tags: android-studio, spek

I'm trying to migrate to Spek 2.x. It looks like everything is set up ok, but I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   clz.java.`package` must not be null   at
>   org.spekframework.spek2.runtime.scope.PathBuilder$Companion.from(Path.kt:86)
>     at
>   org.spekframework.spek2.runtime.SpekRuntime.discover(SpekJvmRuntime.kt:30)
>     at org.spekframework.ide.Spek2ConsoleLauncher.run(console.kt:21)    at
>   org.spekframework.ide.ConsoleKt$main$1.invoke(console.kt:34)  at
>   org.spekframework.ide.ConsoleKt$main$1.invoke(console.kt)     at
>   shadow.com.xenomachina.argparser.SystemExitExceptionKt.mainBody(SystemExitException.kt:74)
>     at
>   shadow.com.xenomachina.argparser.SystemExitExceptionKt.mainBody$default(SystemExitException.kt:72)
>     at org.spekframework.ide.ConsoleKt.main(console.kt:32)

I'm just running this test to keep it simple:

```
class Bla : Spek({
    describe("bla") {
        val a = "a"
        it("is 1 long") {
            assertEquals(true, a.length == 1)
        }
    }
})
```

I also did not get gutter icons at first, but I reverted to an older plugin version https://github.com/spekframework/spek/issues/569

edit:

[image: "package" is null here]

`package` is null here. I have an app with flavors, could that be the issue?

I've set up a new project following the Spek Framework setup info and it gives no issues there.

In what case could this be null?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that there was no `package nl.something.something` at the top

Seems like this was not a prerequisite for Spek 1.x